# Push MFA Enabled AWS Cognito App to apple

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to push my aws cognito with mfa enabled ios app to appple. I  can provide them the login details but how would i handled MFA code generated after login to apple store so that they can approve my app.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this issue ourselves; in the end we disabled MFA for the deployment user, however we used the strategy below while MFA was enabled.

We created a specific user for the deployment, and we enabled MFA which we activated with Google Authenticator. We copied and included the ***secret configuration key***, with instructions to use that key in Google Authenticator, in the App Review Information section of App Store Connect.